# Double populate try but null object returned

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

I have a problem when I tried to retrieve my data from the database

It works with all my find, findOne,etc 
However when I tried to do two populate for one find (see the code below) It returns an UnitCode null but for the MAP attribut I got the correct object with no any problem so why It works only for one plz ??

NodeJs Function :

```
function retrieveResponses(ID,callback){
 ResponseDatabase.
 find({ MAP: ID }).
 populate('UnitCode').
 populate('MAP').
 exec(function (err, data) {     

     callback(data);
 });
};
```

Collection schema :

```
var nameSchemaRS = new mongoose.Schema({
 MainClass: String,
 BookingClass: String,
 CarID: String,
 UnitCode:{type: String, ref: 'Unit' ,required: [true,'No post id found']},
 MAP:{type: String, ref: 'MAP' ,required: [true,'No post id found']},
 Deck:Number,
 Orientation:String,
 Position:String, 
 }, {
 versionKey: false 
});
```

By the way I checked if the codes were the same and it is so I don't know where is my error...

Comment: type should be `ObjectId` not a string

Comment: It works for MAP so why ?

Comment: I find my error and it was only because I target _id on my table 'Unit' so i changed the schema and now its works fine

Comment: Great man!!! Cheers